# How to make an SQL query AWS Athena Presto compatible

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am having an SQL query as follows.

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (i.intime-p.dob)::INTERVAL)/86400 as age
```

It first subtracts two time stamps `i.intime-p.dob` and then apply `extract`, `epoch`, `interval` and divide by `86400` to compute it as `age`.

It should be noted that `p.dob` column is in `2138-07-17` format and `i.intime` is in `2138-07-17 21:20:07` format.

I used the following modified query in AWS Athena to but I am not sure If it is doing the same function as the original `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (i.intime-p.dob)::INTERVAL)/86400 as age`.

My modified AWS Athena query is under.

```
date_diff('second',  p.dob, i.intime) as age
```

Can anyone confirm If both the queries, (the original one and the modified AWS athena one) are generating same values of `age`?

I don't think so they are generating the same values.

My goal is to use AWS athena to replicate the result of simple `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (i.intime-p.dob)::INTERVAL)/86400 as age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you wish to determine the number of days between two dates.

You could simply use:

```sql
SELECT DATE_DIFF('day', p.dob, i.intime)
```

Here's a test:

```sql
SELECT DATE_DIFF('day', CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE), CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE))

Result : 365

SELECT DATE_DIFF('day', CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE), CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE))

Result: 366 (Leap year!)
```